# Error mousemove event can't show button in other frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<div id="background-1" style="background: url('image1.png') no-repeat left center; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left;">
    <div id="button-wrapper" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 100;">
       <input type="button" value="submit">    
    </div>
</div>

<div id="background-2" style="background: url('image2.png') no-repeat right center; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: right;">
    <div id="button-wrapper" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 100;">    
    </div>
</div>​
```

And my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("div[id^=\'button-wrapper\']").parent().mousemove(function(e){
        var _top = e.pageY - 5;
        var _left = e.pageX - 5;
        var _c = jQuery(this);
        var _p = _c.position();;

        if (_top > (_p.top + _c.height())) _top = _p.top + _c.height();
        if (_left > (_p.left + _c.width())) _left = _p.left +_c.width();
        jQuery("div[id^=\'button-wrapper\']").css({
            top: _top,
            left: _left
        });
    });
});​
```

Error when I hover background-2 is event mousemove not run button submit, how to fix it? demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4An3E/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pPn3v/37/) , hope help you !!!

```
var yellow = $('div[id^=\'yellow\']');
var offset = yellow.offset();
var offsetWidth = offset.left + yellow.width();
var offsetHeight = offset.top + yellow.height();

var red = $('#red');

yellow.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    red.css("left", e.pageX);
    red.css("top", e.pageY);
});

red.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if(e.pageX >= offset.left && e.pageY >= offset.top &&
       e.pageX <= offsetWidth && e.pageY <= offsetHeight) {
        red.css("left", e.pageX);
        red.css("top", e.pageY);  
    }               
});
```